# Wasn't Percy 5 days short of his 16th birthday on Doomsday?

Tags: time, percy-jackson

Doomsday, as told in *The Last Olympian*, ends up taking place exactly on Percy's birthday (whatever that is, i don't have the books in front of me).

However, due to the 5 days lost in the Lotus Casino (in *The Lightning Thief*), shouldn't Percy have been 15 years and 360 days old, and not exactly 16?

Were did the extra 5 days come from?

Answer (score 6):

The Lotus Casino only prevents the passage of time *for those inside it*. Outside, time is still passing at the normal rate. Therefore, **Percy's birthday would still be on the same date regardless**.

For instance, if Percy had stayed inside the casino for 100 years, he would still be 100 years older when he comes out - he just wouldn't have aged 100 years. Essentially, he would have had (and missed out on) 100 birthdays in that time without realizing it.